# Hide URL from location bar in VueJs Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am opening a new tab by clicking on a router link like below:
`<router-link to="/mypage" tag="li" active-class="active" exact><a target="_blank">Go to mypage tab</a></router-link>`

After clicking on Goto mypage I am getting the full url in my browser like “http://localhost:8090/mypage”.

I want to hide the “/mypage” from my url. It should only show “http://localhost:8090/”. I have already set the 'Abstract' mode in my router file and it is working fine if I open the URL in same tab but not working when I open a URL in new tab. How can I avoid url in location bar in another tab.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated [feature](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/977) request for what you want to do. However it is not a good idea to avoid displaying the URL path as explained by the community:

> What makes this feature request a bit tricky is that people want to
>   use it for different reasons, some are valid but others we do not
>   completely agree with. This is probably something we will implement or
>   at least provide a convenient alternative solution

If really need to avoid displaying the full URL then you may want to check a server side solution (e.g. [nuxt.js)](https://nuxtjs.org)